# Custom RabbitMessageListner Throws Wrapped Exception

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have custom MessageListener from the custom lib

```java
import org.springframework.amqp.core.*
public class Subscriber {

    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer;
    private ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory;

 public final class ScruberMessageListner implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }

}
```

When  I create a Subscriber, the custom lib will care of starting the Container and managing listener and many more added functionality.

```java
@Configuration
public class BrokerSubscriberConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Subscriber treatmentEventSubscriber(EventConsumer treatmentEventConsumer) {

        return Subscriber.createInitialisedSubscriber(treatmentEventConsumer, configurations, 
          null, true);
    }

}


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fin.bc")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Application loads the bring up message listener but it throws exception upon receiving the message.

---

LogMessage :

```
    SimpleConnection@2a76b80a [delegate=amqp://admin@10.15.190.17:5672/hydra.services, localPort= 50786], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
2020-05-08 15:22:16,251 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] Received message: (Body:'[B@4037c15c(byte[4])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=Hydra.clone.q2, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-50OU2ydRYIghmrPKncVtUw, consumerQueue=Hydra.clone.q2])
2020-05-08 15:22:16,369 WARN org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] Execution of Rabbit message listener failed.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1651)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1603)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1489)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Detected a Non-hex character at 1 or 2 position
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.codec.Hex.decode(Hex.java:62)
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.decrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:40)
    at com.discover.cpp.mba.util.Encryptor.decrypt(Encryptor.java:32)
    at com.discover.cpp.mba.Subscriber$SubscriberMessageListener.onMessage(Subscriber.java:521)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1600)
    ... 10 common frames omitted
2020-05-08 15:22:16,372 DEBUG org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ContainerUtils [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] Rejecting messages (requeue=true)
```

---

Does Rabbit Listener use decoding technique while processing message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Spring AMQP framework. It's your code that is (indirectly) throwing the exception.

```
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.HexEncodingTextEncryptor.decrypt(HexEncodingTextEncryptor.java:40)
    at com.discover.cpp.mba.util.Encryptor.decrypt(Encryptor.java:32)
    at com.discover.cpp.mba.Subscriber$SubscriberMessageListener.onMessage(Subscriber.java:521)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1600)
```

It looks like you are calling some spring security code from your listener.

It appears the inbound message does not have the expected format.

I am guessing `Hex.decode` is expecting a character [a-f,0-9] and the data contains something else.